# How to make html5 video play nice with desktop webapps on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios6, html5-video, iphone-standalone-web-app

I cannot get sound to play for videos on my ipad 4 from a standalone web app, running ios 6.1.3. Check out this fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/6YVAH/

Run it just about anywhere that supports HTML5 video, including within the regular Safari browser on the iPad, and the video clip runs just fine, sound and video. Save it as a chromeless standalone iPad desktop web app, however, and the video plays with no sound. I have also experimented with audio files, and again no sound when saved to the desktop.

The html is about is simple as you can possibly get. You can fix it by removing the apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta tag:

```
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

but that eliminates the possibility of saving to the desktop as a chromeless app, which is my requirement. Anyone know a workaround, or is this just a bug in ios 6.1.3 that will hopefully get fixed in 7.0?

Comment: I'm getting bored of these ios7 bug as a web app developper

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, can't play sound. It works in safari, but not when using apple-mobile-web-app-capable!

Answer (score 0):

I've just had exactly these symptoms on iOS 7. My webapp sounds worked in Safari, but not when lanched as a fullscreen app from the homescreen.

Turned out my ringtone volume was set to mute and by increasing this my homescreen app sounds worked.

It seems that Safari uses the media volume (as I would expect) and for some bizarre reason homescreen apps use the ringtone volume.